# $stateprovider multiple routes angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How do we have multiple routes for in $stateProvider. I want to have multiple based on different url templates

```
 .config([
'$stateProvider',

function(sp) {
    sp.state('reservations', {
    url: '/reservations?t',
    templateUrl: 'src/reservations/te.html',
    data: {
      backState: "back",
      shortTitle: "Reservations"
    },
```

I want to define another route based on for 
url `/reservations?edit=true`
Similar like when

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to the `templateUrl`, it can take $stateParams as parameter.

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
    return '/partials/contacts.' + $stateParams.filterBy + '.html';
  }
})
```

From https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates